# How Can I display % value in Pie chart Legend Item text using C3.js?

Tags: c3.js

I have created Pie chart and it is working ok. In Pie Chart, Labels are showing % values and it is also fine. But now I just want to show % value in Legend item text also.

```
var ChartDesignCreated = c3.generate({
    bindto: "#Chart1",
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['Football', 10)],
            ['Cricket', 10)],
        ],
        type: 'pie'
        }
    });
```

Legend item text should be display like :

`Football = 50%`

`Cricket = 50%`

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no built-in way to do that.
However, you can just put percentage into data label texts before chart rendering:

```
var columns = [
    ['data1', 30],
    ['data2', 120]
];

var total = columns.reduce(function(sum, item) {
    return sum + item[1]
}, 0);

columns = columns.map(function(item) {
    return [
        item[0] + ' = ' + d3.format('.1%')(item[1] / total),
        item[1]
    ]
});

var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: columns,
        type : 'pie'
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Dimmy/y2LLftx0/2/

Comment: It is very helpful. Problem solved.
Thank you so much